# python one liner for creating dictionary from list

Tags: python-2.7

I am learning dictionary comprehension, and wrote the following code.
The output of the list 'lines' looks like this:

```
[['Color', 'Blue', 'Model', 'Ford'], ['Color', 'Green', 'Model', 'Honder'], ['Color', 'Pink', 'Model', 'peugeot']]
```

'

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

import pprint
d={}

FILE='File.txt'
with open(FILE, 'r') as Data:

    lines = [line.split() for line in Data ]
    #print lines

    for x in lines:
        d[x[0]] = x[1]
        d[x[2]] = x[3]

        pprint.pprint(d)
```

Basically i am trying to figure out how i can convert the above for loop into a single line.

So far i tried the below code:

```
e = {x[0]:x[1] for x in lines}
```

But that would only give me the very last entry of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a clean solution using the third form of the [dict constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> l=[['Color', 'Blue', 'Model', 'Ford'], ['Color', 'Green', 'Model', 'Honder'], ['Color', 'Pink', 'Model', 'peugeot']]
>>> [dict(izip(d[::2], d[1::2])) for d in l]
[{'Color': 'Blue', 'Model': 'Ford'}, {'Color': 'Green', 'Model': 'Honder'}, {'Color': 'Pink', 'Model': 'peugeot'}]
>>>
```